# Alerta con Sweet Alert no aparece al guardar

Tags: php, mysql, sweetalert2

Estoy intentando agregar a mi formulario PHP alertas con SWEET ALERT, para que cuando agregue una carrera, se muestre un mensaje indicando si se realizo correctamente o hubo un error al guardar el registro. He visto algunos ejemplos y según entiendo, para mostrar una alerta es solo cargar el link de la librería y luego llamar a la alerta, pero alguna razón no me funciona. Tengo cargada la librería y he cargado el código para ejecutar la alerta, pero presiono guardar y no aparece la alerta y el registro es guardado sin problemas.
Agradecería si me pueden indicar que estoy haciendo mal o que me falta.

Aquí dejo el código de mi pagina agregar_carrera.php.

```
<?php 
include "conexion.php";

if(!empty($_POST))
{
    $alert='';
    if(empty($_POST['nombre_carrera']))
    {
        echo"<script type='text/javascript'>
             swal('Campo Obligatorio'); window.location='agregar_carreras.php';</script>"; ////CARGO LA ALERTA
    }
    else
    {
        $nombre_carrera = $_POST['nombre_carrera'];
        
        $query_insert = mysqli_query($conection,"INSERT INTO 
        carrera(nombre_carrera)VALUES('$nombre_carrera')");
        
        if($query_insert)
        {
            echo"<script type='text/javascript'>
             swal('Ingreso Exitoso'); window.location='agregar_carreras.php';</script>"; ////CARGO LA ALERTA
        }
        else
        {
            echo"<script type='text/javascript'>
             swal('Error'); window.location='agregar_carreras.php';</script>";  ////CARGO LA ALERTA
        }
    }
}   
?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Nueva Carrera</title>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>  ////LINK DE LA LIBRERIA DE SWEET ALERT
 </head>
 <body>
 <section id="container">
    <div class="form_register">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <label for="nombre_carrera">Nombre Carrera</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre_carrera" id="nombre_carrera">

                <button type="submit" class="btn_save">Guardar</button>
            </form>
    </div>
 </section>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacerlo de esta manera tal y como se explica en la documentación de sweetalert ([ver documentación](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/)):

```
if($query_insert)
    {
       echo "<script type='text/javascript'>swal("Ingreso Exitoso", "¡Bienvenido!", "success")";
       echo "window.location='agregar_carreras.php';</script>"; ////CARGO LA ALERTA
    }
```

Lo que estamos realizando es, complementar el código de una manera mejor estructurada donde presentamos 3 argumentos dentro del paréntesis, el prmiero es el mensaje principal de la alerta, el segundo es el mensaje secundaro o explicativo de lo que se va a realizar y el tercero es el comando que implementa el botón que indica que se entendió el mensaje y continúa con el window.location que lleva a la página indicada.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero sigue sin mostrar la alerta.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).